# Is there a language that checks the validity of a proof?

Tags: predicate-logic

Is there a language/interpreter, that checks the validity of a proof with which you can define a model and use whole predicate logic?

Comment: Have a look at Coq. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq

Comment: Check also [Adga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)) or [Isabelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)).